# Unit test expressJwt middleware with mocha js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, express-jwt

I am trying to figure out how to unit test the following route using Mocha.

```
router.delete('/auth/cut', expressJwt({ secret: global.secret }), function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.status(401).send().end();
    } else {
        fileProcessor.cut(req, res);
    }
});
```

I am using Middleware that validates `JsonWebTokens` and sets `req.user`.
This is the test that i have

```
it('DELETE /auth/cut responds Success' , function (done) {
            request(sharedVars.server)
                .delete('/api/archive/auth/cut')
                .set('Authorization', 'Bearer tokenid')
                .set('filename', 'dictionary.zip')
                .end(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                expect(result.status).to.equal(200);
                done();
            });
        });
```

The following lines

```
.set('Authorization', 'Bearer tokenid')
.set('filename', 'dictionary.zip')
```

Are being passed via the `Header`

When i run the test i always get a `404 status`, meaning the route is not found.
What am i doing wrong? I think the problem is because of the Middleware inside the route.